# Issue with og:image and Facebook Recommendations

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, thumbnails, facebook-recommendations

We have a site here: http://blistergearreview.com/ which we recently setup the open graph meta tags on. The issue that we cannot figure out is on the homepage we have the Facebook recommendations plugin and even though the og:image displays correctly using Facebook's lint tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) for all of the posts in the recommendations box they don't actually display in the box itself. We've tried several things and are stuck. Has anyone else had an issue similar to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your image (http://blistergearreview.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/012011_BlisterLogo_white2.png) is 309px x 73px.  This is larger than the acceptable 3:1 aspect ratio maximum Facebook accepts.  Get the width/height aspect ratio less than 3.0 and your image should appear.

I just wish Facebook would check the size in the linter tool so it would error out on images that don't comply (as you would have seen the error there).

For additional requirements, please see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 2):

I also recommend using a jpeg/jpg image instead of png. 
You may be able to see it using facebook debugging tools but when a user shares one of your links it may still be showing an outdated image.
It seems that facebook doesnt like png files...